# Generating list of facebook friends using Facebook's Graph API

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I've found a few related questions here on how to program with the graph api, but none of them connect the documentation to actual implementation, which is essentially what this one is about.

I'm trying to build a Facebook app with php. Basically I want to display a list of all the friends enrolled at the same college as you. So how would I go about doing that (I plan on using the "education" query)? I've already got the user to log in and I can print the user name.

I've seen tons of examples of how to execute Facebook queries like this:

```
GET https://graph.facebook.com/me?fields=name,birthday,photos.limit(10).fields(id, picture)
```

So do I just plunk that URL in as a line of code (and if so, how do I display it - with echo?)?

I've never programmed with json or fql before and I'm a php novice. Everyone's said to watch the video at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/ and read that documentation. Unfortunately nothing in that documentation makes any link between the video and how to actually program anything. So that's not very helpful. However I do feel like there has to be something important about that url generated right after the "GET/POST/DELETE" box in the graph api explorer.

So what am I missing? How do write my php code to get and print a list of friends who go to your college?

My current php code, for reference (CSS is from an external document on my server - there's some boilerplate text and boxes in there, I know!):

```
<?php
  // Setting up php sdk
  require_once('src/facebook.php');

  $config = array(
    'appId' => '196743413820733',
    'secret' => 'f39853b06a0607c1efd272d071c2f371',
  );

  $facebook = new Facebook($config);
  $user_id = $facebook->getUser();

?>
<html>
  <head>
  <!-- Getting facebook-style CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyles.css" media="screen" />
  </head>
  <body>

  <?php
    if($user_id) {

      // We have a user ID, so probably a logged in user.
      // If not, we'll get an exception, which we handle below.
      try {

        $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me','GET');
        echo "Name: " . $user_profile['name'];
        echo "<br/> Here are some things about yourself";

        echo '<div class="fbgreybox" style="width: 500px;"><p class="fbbody">
            Recognize this general purpose grey box? </p>
        </div>';

      } catch(FacebookApiException $e) {
        // If the user is logged out, you can have a 
        // user ID even though the access token is invalid.
        // In this case, we'll get an exception, so we'll
        // just ask the user to login again here.
        $login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl(); 
        echo 'Please <a href="' . $login_url . '">login.</a>';
        error_log($e->getType());
        error_log($e->getMessage());
      }   
    } else {

      // No user, print a link for the user to login
      $login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl();
      echo 'Please <a href="' . $login_url . '">login.</a>';

    }

  ?>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi, possibly there is lot of tutorial and documents are available,i found a better one here http://hybridauth.sourceforge.net/

Comment: maybe this will help? http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/wrangling-with-the-facebook-graph-api/ or http://faceconn.com/using-graph-api-php

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to add proper permission to access education history of user & user's friends, which you can achieved by doing this but remember user_education_history is to access User education while friends_education_history is for User's friends education history:

```
$params = array(
'scope' => 'user_education_history, friends_education_history, user_location, email');
$loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl($params);
```

And to access education field you have to modify one line from your code like this:
    $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me?fields=name,education,email','GET');

You can use below code to just print your $user_profile and then parse it according to your requirements:

```
<pre><?php print_r($user_profile); ?></pre>
```

Probably its too late answer for your query but might be helpful for some other.